# Работа BinaryReader и BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, .net

Никак не могу понять как работают `BinaryReader` и `BinaryWriter`?
  Зачем в конструктор передаётся `true`, написано "чтобы при необходимости поток оставался открытым", что это означает?
 
При какой необходимости поток должен оставаться открытым?
Как вообще осуществляется передача строки в `BinaryWriter`? Если я правильно понял, то через `BinaryWriter` отправляется, что-то вроде массива типа `Byte`, то есть каждый символ кодируется как набор 0-й и 1-ц и добавляется в массив и пока не будет достигнут конец сообщения, данные будут отправляться.

```
reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true);
writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true);
```

Также не понятно как работает метод `BinaryReader.ReadString()`? Как я понял он получает длину строки, потом саму строку. То есть декодирует  массив типа `Byte` в указанную кодировку и сразу записывает декодированные символы в строку, до тех пор пока он не достиг конца строки, и если отправка сообщения приостановлена, то он будет ждать пока она не возобновиться.
 
На [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring(v=vs.110).aspx) сказано, что "метод `BinaryReader.ReadString ()` считывает число блоками по 7 бит", это значит он получает число и делит его на блоки по 7 бит?
Сразу же возникают другие вопросы: зачем он делит число на блоки по 7 бит, какой тип данных передаётся в `BinaryReader.ReadString ()`? Я думаю, что передаётся массив типа `Byte` то есть само сообщение, а перед ним некое число типа `Int32`- длина строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `BinaryWriter` реализует интерфейс `IDisposable`. Передавая в конструктор `true` в качестве последнего параметра можно задать, будет ли писатель закрыт при вызове `IDisposable.Dispose`.

Что касается "число блоками по 7 бит", то это имеется ввиду используемый в этих читателях/писателях способ сжатой записи для `int`:

- в каждый байт записываются по 7 бит, начиная с младших разрядов;
- если все более старшие биты в числе после записанных нулевые, то запись останавливается;
- старший бит используется в качестве индикатора окончания числа, т.е. если он выставлен, то следующий байт содержит продолжение числа, а если нет - то число закончилось;

Такой подход позволяет экономить место при записи коротких чисел. Например для записи числа 127 потребуется тольк 1 байт вместо 4, для 1257 потребуется 2 байта. Однако при этом получается оверхед для больших чисел, да и запись / чтение производится медленее.

Перед строкой записывается ее длинна в такой упакованной форме, а затем содержимое строки как есть.

Comment: Почему в данном случае в 1-м байте 7бит, а не 8бит? И какой тип данных передаётся `int`  бывает разный: `Int32`, `Int16`?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев В каждом байте по-прежнему 8 бит, но последний из них относится не к сохраненному числу, а используется в качестве флажка. Используется метод [`BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Значит, возвращаемое значение Int32 в сжатом формате. А строка передаётся как String или неявно преобразуется в тип Byte, а потом `reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true)` уже только преобразует в тип String ?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев Возвращаемое значение в обычном формате, это хранится в сжатом.

Comment: А строка передаётся как String или неявно преобразуется в тип `Byte`, а потом `reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true)` уже только преобразует в тип String ?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев В методе `BinaryReader.ReadString` прямо указан возвращаемый тип - `String`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, чёт я это сам не заметил